# how to pass string value to javascript as function parameter from html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im embedding html codes in java , I have to pass a string value from html to javascript function, I have tried something like this

```
out.print("<script>init("+macId+")</script>");
```

but it  didn't pass any value if I pass some integer value then it will be fine, then  tried this which I have seen in some example

```
out.print("<script>init(\'"+macId+"\')</script>");
```

but the result is same ..can anybody help me to solve this, is this method is the right one I need to follow?

Comment: why dont you assign the variable to some input value and get the value of that element in your function with jquery or js.

Comment: like if some hidden div? then using jQuery  "div id.innerHtml "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape `'` in string:

```
out.print("<script>init('" + macId + "')</script>");
```